# Differences in perl and python regex / matching and caputuring minimum length

Tags: python, perl

I would expect this python script:

```
import re

path='assign-e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510.json'

print(path)

m = re.compile('[a-z0-9]{8,}')
print(m.match(path))

print(re.match('[\w\d]{8,}', path))
```

to behave similarly (i.e.: to match in the same places) as this perl one:

```
use strict;
$\ = "\n"; $, = "\t";
my $path='assign-e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510.json';
print($path);
print $path =~ /([\w\d]{8,})/;
```

However the output of the python scrip is:

```
assign-e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510.json
None
None
```

and perl returns:

```
assign-e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510.json
e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510
```

Why is that? How do I capture the 32 char md5 hash in the path name in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex for `md5`-

```
re.findall(r"([a-fA-F\d]{32})", data)

#output
['e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510']
```

also, you need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`

```
re.search('[\w\d]{8,}', path).group(0)

#output
'e398846de42d98b1f79109926d0da510'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `m.search` instead of `m.match`. The latter only matches the beginning of the string.